# Is it necessary to show "Location Access" Prompt every time requesting for the location?

Tags: android, permissions, location

Recently google made it mandatory to show alert message to describe why location access is required, before requesting for location access.

This is the link where all the details have been mentioned -- https://support.google.com/googlepl...onstration,see-an-example-video-demonstration

And, This is how the sample prompt looks like
[image]

But Showing such a message to users every time they are requesting location is little bit annoying. Because, Our users has to do Check-In and Check-Out on daily basis.

Hence, Can I show this message only once unless they have uninstalled the app?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because questions about app store terms of service are off topic here.

Comment: @GabeSechan May I know what do you mean by **questions about app store terms of service**? If you let me know the reason then it would be meaningful for your down voting.

Comment: This isn't a technical question, because there's no technical reason you ever need to show this.  Your question is about what Google wants you to do to be on the app store.  And those kinds of questions are off topic here.

Answer (score 2):

This alert message is required to be shown when users are asked to grant **access** to their location. That is when **runtime permissions** are requested. It is not required to show this alert dialog before accessing the location everytime.
If permission is reset, denied or revoked, the permission will be requested again and alert should be shown again.